# Efficiently querying MSSQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given the task of getting some data from a MSSQL database. I am not the DB owner and I do not have the ability to make any changes or add any indices or anything. I have to work with what I have. (I think the DB designer was on drugs.)

The DB is accessed via a python script, but I will show pseudo code here as it's the SQL that important.

For this there are 5 items of data, let's call them A, B, C, D, and RecipeInstance. In the database, A, B, C, and D are concatenated and stored in a single column as A@B@C@D. There is a one to many relationship between 'A@B@C@D' and RecipeInstance.

My 2 tasks are:

1) Given A, B, C, and D get all the recipes

This is easy enough conceptually, but my query is very slow. Here's my query for this:

```
SELECT PDEName as recipe
FROM RecipeInstance
WHERE PdeInstanceId
IN (SELECT DISTINCT PdeInstanceId FROM RecipeTableValue WHERE CellValue
IN (SELECT DISTINCT PDEName FROM RunInstance WHERE PdeInstanceId
IN (SELECT PdeInstanceId FROM RunTableValue WHERE CellValue = 'A@B@C@D')))
```

This query takes 16 seconds. I really need to make it faster. I tried breaking it down into 4 seperate queries, but together they still took 16 seconds. There are no useful indices on these tables, and I cannot create any. Can anyone think of anyway to make this faster?

2) Given A, B, C, and Recipe get D

This is more complicaed, since there's no relationship back from RecipeInstance to TargetInstance where D is. Here is what I came up with:

```
select PdeName as TargetPdeName
FROM TargetInstance
WHERE PdeName like 'A@B@C@%'

# this query returns between 20,000 and 40,000 rows

foreach TargetPdeName returned from the above query
    SELECT PDEName as RecipePdeName
    FROM RecipeInstance
    WHERE PdeInstanceId
    IN (SELECT DISTINCT PdeInstanceId FROM RecipeTableValue WHERE CellValue
    IN (SELECT DISTINCT PDEName FROM RunInstance WHERE PdeInstanceId
    IN (SELECT PdeInstanceId FROM RunTableValue WHERE CellValue = TargetPdeName)))

    if RecipePdeName == Recipe:
        # this is the one we want
        (a, b, c, d) = TargetPdeName.split('@')
        return d
```

So the problem here is obviously that I have to run tens of thousands of queries, each one taking 16 seconds.  Can anyone see how I can traverse this relationship backwards in an efficient manner?

Comment: What about joining those tables and then adding where clause? part1

Comment: Anytime you use wildcards in the middle of strings you will force serial DB reads, so if you can separate or narrow down the result set on the LIKE 'A@...' performance will improve. It also seems to me you can be using joins to narrow down wildcard evaluations.

Comment: whereever you select select where A in (select ...) you are asking for trouble performance wise -- convert these to the equivalen select where exits (select * from). When won't need the disctinct clause in the subquery either

Comment: Not sure how I can use a join or remove the wildcard. I have to get all the possible A@B@C@ and look at all the rows to find the D I want. In the last IN clause I could do WHERE CellValue like 'A@B@C@%'but then when I get a match, how to I know what the D is? And I still have the wildcard.

Comment: @Gary Walker - can you give me an example of what you mean? I don't sew how to do this with a 'where exists' clause.

Comment: select data1, data2 from table1 t1 where exists (select * from table2 T2 where t2.data1 = t1.data1)

Comment: @Gary Walker - I really appreciate the help, but I don't see how to apply this to the 4 level query I have and then get the data I ultimately need. I need to match the RecipePdeName with the passed in recipe value and when I find a match extract the "D" value from the CellValue in RunTableValue. Sorry for being so dense. Thanks!

Comment: Having the same column name in different table smell of the possibility of a short circuit (or of bad design) have you explored the possibility?

Comment: At the moment the question is not answerable in a useful way because we need more information. Please detail the schema (including indexes) of the relevant tables. Post the actual execution plan that you are getting as XML (maybe on pastebin). Maybe you are just out of luck and need a solution outside of the database (e.g. a cache).

Comment: @Serpiton I know it's a bad design. As I said in my original post, I did not design it and I cannot modify it.

Comment: @usr - how do I get the execution plan? I am very experienced with Sybase, Oracle, MySQL, and Postgres, but I have no experience with MSSQL.

Comment: @LarryMartell there's a green toolbar item. Execute the query with this option set and the plan is in another result tab. (Don't confuse this with the estimated plan.) Right click and save as XML. Upload anywhere you like. Do you have experience interpreting execution plans in the databases you listed?

Comment: @usr - I do not have any GUI access to the database. It exists as just an IP address to me and I access it from a Linux box using pyodbc from python.

Comment: @LarryMartell that's sucks, I was hoping for the short circuit

Comment: @LarryMartell can't help you with that. If Google doesn't know, this would be a another valid SO question ("How to get the XML execution plan from SQL Server with pyodbc?").

Answer (score 1):

Below are `JOIN` and `EXISTS` queries. Try both and let us know how they run.

1)

JOIN version

```
SELECT DISTINCT reci.PDEName as recipe
FROM RecipeInstance reci
JOIN RecipeTableValue rectv ON reci.PdeInstanceId = rectv.PdeInstanceId
JOIN RunInstance runi ON rectv.CellValue = runi.PDEName
JOIN RunTableValue runtv ON runi.PdeInstanceId = runtv.PdeInstanceId 
WHERE runtv.CellValue = 'A@B@C@D'
```

EXISTS version

```
SELECT PDEName as recipe
FROM RecipeInstance reci
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM RecipeTableValue rectv 
    WHERE rectv.PdeInstanceId = reci.PdeInstanceId
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM RunInstance runi 
        WHERE runi.PDEName = rectv.CellValue
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM RunTableValue runtv 
            WHERE runi.PdeInstanceId = runtv.PdeInstanceId
            AND CellValue = 'A@B@C@D'            
        )
    )
)
```

2) **EDIT:** To split `ti.PdeName` by `@` and extract the last value you'll need to define your own function. See [How do I split a string so I can access item x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

JOIN version

```
SELECT DISTINCT ti.PdeName
FROM RecipeInstance reci
JOIN RecipeTableValue rectv ON reci.PdeInstanceId = rectv.PdeInstanceId
JOIN RunInstance runi ON rectv.CellValue = runi.PDEName
JOIN RunTableValue runtv ON runi.PdeInstanceId = runtv.PdeInstanceId 
JOIN TargetInstance ti ON runtv.CellValue = ti.PdeName
WHERE reci.PDEName = "MyRecipe"
```

EXISTS version

```
SELECT ti.PdeName
FROM TargetInstance ti
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM RunTableValue runtv
    WHERE runtv.CellValue = ti.PdeName
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM RunInstance runi
        WHERE runi.PdeInstanceId = runtv.PdeInstanceId 
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM RecipeTableValue rectv
            WHERE rectv.CellValue = runi.PDEName
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM RecipeInstance reci
                WHERE reci.PdeInstanceId = rectv.PdeInstanceId
                AND reci.PDEName = "MyRecipe"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Using exist clauses is better than join since it will avoid the duplicates that will occur. Original post was use distinct clause to kill the dupes.

Comment: I will have to try #1 on Monday and see if it yields the proper result set and what the performance is. But for #2, it doesn't take into account the passed in A, B, C, or recipe and doesn't yield the D I need.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes, that's correct. This looks good - I will try it on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: Rewriting IN/EXISTS to joins is not necessary with SQL Server, except if you need to apply query hints. In fact, you worsen performance because IN can stop pulling rows as soon as one match was found.

Comment: For the 1st query,there is under a 1 second difference between the 3 versions(my original one,and the 2 variations above). I am going to see if I can get some indices created,and if not,look into running a script off hours that will create a simple table with the direct D/recipe mapping. The database is only updated once a day,so that would work,I just don't know how long that would take to run. But with the second query,it's a big win.The join version takes under 1 second and gives me just what I need(a lot better then 30000 16 second queries). FYI the exists version takes around 3 seconds.